# What might cause an Uncaught TypeError with an Object Prototype that occurs in the AOT build but not in the development environment?

Tags: angular, ng-build

I have made an Angular application that tests well in the developement environment. I have ported it to a sandbox server and run `ng build` with associated parameters for base-href and environment. When I run the application in the sandbox environment, I see the following error:

[image]

This error does not appear in the development environment.

The trouble I face is that because of AOT compilation I am not able to identify the class that is causing the error.

What should I do to track down this error?

Why might it appear in the build file but not in the JIT files?

All help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: hi, are you using APP_INITIALIZER  ?

Comment: I will have to research that. I'm not familiar with APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: I have researched APP_INITIALIZER, and I can officially state now that I have no custom functions running during the initialization process.

Answer (score 0):

I never found an answer to the question, but the issue is now resolved.

I upgraded from angular 5.8 to angular 6.1. The upgraded systems do not produce builds with the same errors. I am now able to move onto my next challenge, which is the URI having additional content, which apparently the BASE_HREF being set to '/client/' does not account for, but that is for another post on another day.

The above question resolved by upgrading the angular system, in this case.